# Joining array of items from another table to first table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a table defined as.

```
survey_question_answers

    id  |  surveyId | questionId | title | description | creationDate

survey_questions
        id  |  surveyId | title | description | creationDate
```

I am using mysql query

```
SELECT `SurveyQuestion`.*, `Answer`.* FROM `uaehub`.`survey_questions` AS `SurveyQuestion` LEFT JOIN `uaehub`.`survey_question_answers` AS `Answer` ON (`SurveyQuestion`.`id` = `Answer`.`questionId`)  WHERE `SurveyQuestion`.`id` = 1  GROUP BY SurveyQuestion.id
```

THe problem is, it is only fetching 1 answer instead of all answers. How can i modify the query to fetch all answers attached to my surveyQuestion

I am trying to do this in cakephp

```
$questions = $this->SurveyQuestion->find('all', array(   
                'conditions' => array('SurveyQuestion.id' => $survey['id']),
                'fields' => array(
                        'SurveyQuestion.*',
                        'Answer.*'
                ),
                'joins' => array(
                        array(
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'table' => 'survey_question_answers',
                                'alias' => 'Answer',
                                'conditions' => array('SurveyQuestion.id = Answer.questionId')
                        ),                                                  
                ),
                'group' => array(
                        'SurveyQuestion'
                ),                
        ));
```

This is what i want

```
{
    "SurveyQuestion": {
      "id": "1",
      "surveyId": "1",
      "title": "Did you exercised early in the morning?",
      "description": "If Yes, please choose Yes. If no please choose NO",
      "creationDate": "2016-12-02 09:39:18"
    },
    "Answer": [{
      "id": "1",
      "surveyId": "1",
      "questionId": "1",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "creationDate": "2016-12-02 09:39:44"
    },
{
      "id": "2",
      "surveyId": "1",
      "questionId": "1",
      "answer": "NO",
      "creationDate": "2016-12-02 09:39:44"
    }]
  }
```

something like this,
having an array of answers attached to question

what i am getting atm is

```
{
    "SurveyQuestion": {
      "id": "1",
      "surveyId": "1",
      "title": "Did you exercised early in the morning?",
      "description": "If Yes, please choose Yes. If no please choose NO",
      "creationDate": "2016-12-02 09:39:18"
    },
    "Answer": {
      "id": "1",
      "surveyId": "1",
      "questionId": "1",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "creationDate": "2016-12-02 09:39:44"
    }
  }
```

Note , this is format of cakephp

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a GROUP BY? This is the reason you get only one line. Leave out the group by and it should work.

GROUP BY will group the results so that (in your case) for any surveyQuestion.id (= for every question) only one row is returned.

Comment: if i do that it gives me multiple rows with questions attached, remember i am also getting a number of questions and with each question there should be number of answers attached inside

Comment: Could you give an example of what you get and what exactly you want.

Comment: Every row will have a question and answer (you join both tables).